# Convert mp4 video to m3u8 format with C# ffmpack

Tags: c#, .net, powershell, ffmpeg, sharpffmpeg

I can convert the file with the extension mp4 in my hand from the code line related to PowerShell to m3u8 format.

```
ffmpeg -i inputVideo.mp4 -profile:v baseline -level 3.0 -s 960x540 -start_number 0 -hls_time 10 -hls_list_size 0 -f hls outputVideo.m3u8
```

But I want to automate this process using C#. I did as written in the document on Microsoft's site, but I could not add the relevant parameters. Has anyone done anything like this before? or how can I follow a path.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/developer/hosting/adding-and-invoking-commands?view=powershell-7&fbclid=IwAR05LjyIa8Yv5YFVh-HcbWH5YqmaeQKJ8LzaGsCQxjvJBIepdLAx7E39y7Y

Comment: The parameter should not have dashes so they would be : .AddParameter("i", "inputVideo.mp4").  It also looks like you need to have full path name for any reference files.

Comment: @jdweng  like as  .AddParameter("i", "inputVideo.mp4")
.AddParameter("i", "baseline")
.AddParameter("i","3.0") ?

Comment: No.  .AddParameter("i", "inputVideo.mp4") .AddParameter("profile:v", "baseline") .AddParameter("level","3.0") Also if the file is not in same folder and the c# exe add pathname "c:\temp\inputVideo.mp4"

Comment: thank you for the answer. I'll try again the way you say it, and share the result again. @jdweng

Comment: @jdweng Could you post this as answer so the OP can accept?